# Categories widget in WooCommerce Storefront theme not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have installed the Storefront theme for WooCommerce and under that a child theme with zero configuration. All pretty standard.

I've add one test product and 2 categories. However, these do not show up in the categories widget in the sidebar.

The product and categories are published and if I set the store to show categories on the Shop home, they appear. But they never show up in the sidebar widget at all.

**Widget (admin)**

[image]

**Categories**

[image]

**Sidebar widget**

[image]

Is this an issue / bug with the theme?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This categories widget relates to posts not products.
You should use "Products categories" widget.
Cheers.